# Can a POST to Django REST Framework backend trigger an update of the frontend through Django Channels?

Tags: django, database, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

**Background:**

I am creating a chat app using Django Channels that is the pilot for a more complicated app down the road that will need real-time data updates. Right now, the backend for the chat app is set up with Channels and Django REST Framework. When the chat app is opened, a websocket is created and messages are sent through the websocket, as any other basic chat app does. Also, when a message is sent, the message is posted to the REST framework to store the message in the database.

**Question:**

This app that I will be creating has other resources that will be posting data to the Django REST Framework, and this data needs to be shown on the front end in real-time. My idea for this is when the REST framework gets a POST request from one of the resources, the data from the POST request gets sent as a message through the websocket so the data gets updated on the frontend. Is there a way to do this? I have been struggling finding resources on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it is explained [in the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers).
You can interact with the consumer through the channel layer from anywhere in your code. And this includes your DRF views, serializer, etc.

So, when you receive the message in your DRF view, you can do something like this:

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("chat", {"type": "send_message", "message": message})
```

Where "chat" is the group name and `send_message` is a handler in your consumer that sends the message and `message` is the message you want to send. Could be a dict or some other serializable type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Ken4scholars. I am trying to figure out where I would send the message to the channel layer. When a POST is made to the DRF of an app, I want the message to be sent to the channel layer, but I'm unsure what element of DRF runs when a POST request is made. Do you know what element handles the requests (Serializer, ViewSet, Model, etc.)?

Comment: Then I would advice taking more tutorials or reading the DRF docs. That is the very fundamental part of any web framework so I don't think you can develop any project successfully without knowledge about how and where the request is handled